# KDE does not notice laptop running on battery

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, kde, battery

After upgrading to Kubuntu 14.04, KDE does not notice that the laptop is running on battery!

The battery icon continues to show the 'charging' symbol. But the battery level shown in the icon keeps reducing as I use the laptop. When I hover the mouse on the icon, the tooltip displays the battery level as 50%, 40%, 19% etc.

When the battery goes down to low level (20% as defined in System settings -> Power -> Advanced Settings), there is no warning. The same is the case when the battery goes to the critical level.

How can I set this right?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I've tried different things like changing precents and adding other options. No luck.
Does anyone found any solution for this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that after killing and restarting plasmashell, the battery monitor begins to function properly on my end.

Comment: Please contemplate offering a more complete answer.  A short step by step guide would be ideal.

Comment: I think Adrint is referring to something like this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/484989/panel-icons-disappear-at-startup/485020#485020 for KDE Plasma instead of Unity.