# How to get back language icon that disappeared from my system(14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, indicator

In the Ubuntu 14.04, when I reboot my machine, the language icon keyboard disappeared.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04:

System Settings → Text Entry → Lower left corner: **[v] Show current input source in the menu bar**

Comment: this doesn't do anything for me :(

Comment: Logout + login? if that doesn't help, then http://askubuntu.com/questions/484989/panel-icons-disappear-at-startup

Comment: no it does not help. something is wrong.

Comment: Also works for 16.04. Thanks!