# Ubuntu 14.04/Unity lost almost all indicators

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator

Like my title said: I lost almost indicators on unity / Ubuntu 14.04.

I have tried restart indicator-sessions, deactivate practically all my software-indicators (maybe conflict).. but I have only Language/mail/sound/hour/gear all other app-indicators runs but not appear in the indicators bar.

Any idea?

Comment: What does `ps x | grep --ignore-case indicator` show?

Comment: @Fabby I put the result of this command on pastbin here : http://pastebin.com/paiYqxr6

Comment: I finaly found bug tracker about this issus on launchpad here https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1310200 I try the update -proposed

Comment: You should post that as an answer.  A bug *is* an answer!  ;-)  And then accept your own answer! >:-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by running `sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete`. All my indicators are then reappeared I de-installed and everything remained. Why is working? I do not know, probably the installation of it has made it possible to correct a corrupted or missing file. (maybe) :)

Comment: You can accept your answer by pressing the green tick next to it :)

Comment: You may also be interested in reading [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484989/panel-icons-disappear-at-startup/485020#485020) by hannesvr which explains how to bring the indicator icons back without either uninstalling or installing anything and without rebooting the computer.